Time between BTLE scanning and broadcast in Android
In a scenario, when Android is doing scanning and its stopped and then we do a BTLE broadcast from Android, typically, how much minimum time is there between scanning stop and broadcast start?
I know probably its not defined anywhere but a ballpark figure can help me.
Thanks and Regards,
WA

There are several variables when it comes to this including the phone's processing speed, the device hardware (e.g. Samsung, Motorola, Sony, etc), the underlying vendor stack that is being used, etc - but in most cases I would say it is hundreds of milliseconds or even less. You may be able to test this in your code by adding a timer before stopping the scanning (e.g. before stopScan()) and then stopping the timer after initiating the broadcast (e.g. after startAdvertising()).
